# Serialize JSON without wrapping in [ ]

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to make an HTTP PUT request to a CouchDB server. I am converting an NSString instance to NSData. I then convert this NSData instance to an NSArray and attempt to PUT this to CouchDB. So something like this:

```
//convert string to NSData
    NSData *docData = [@"{\"name\":\"nick\"}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSData to NSArray
    NSArray *arrayJson = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:docData options:kNilOptions error:nil],nil];
```

I am then creating an HTTP PUT request using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (which is rad btw ;))

The problem is that this creates a json string which looks like:

```
[{"name":"nick"}]
```

This is valid JSON but Couch complains with 400 Bad JSON. Removing the [ ]s fixes the problem. I'm sure these brackets are the result of converting NSData to NSArray but I'm not sure how else to accomplish this using NSJSONSerialization. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

**Edit**

For clarity sake let me explain the problem I was having further. I am creating a document using the CouchDB HTTP API using a PUT HTTP request. The document could be hand coded JSON and that is why I have this parsing challenge. Couch expects a single document to create. Therefore it expects a single JSON object. NOT an array of them. That seems to be why [{"key":"value"}] returns a 400 HTTP response from Couch. Even if the array contains a single object. Seems a bit picky that the API wouldn't just infer correctly based on the array length.. but I guess you could argue either way. See the selected answer below. This is what I was looking for. Thanks to all those who responded!

Comment: Where are you creating the actual data that you send?  Why do you need to use NSArray?

Comment: I would rather not use NSArray. I would like the HTTP body to contain the JSON like this: {"name":"nick"}. How else can I deserialize a JSON string? Directly to NSDictionary somehow?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  You should just be able to send `docData` above to the server.  It is a valid JSON string.

Comment: It is valid JSON. Agreed :) I will update my post to be more clear. When creating single document using the CouchDB HTTP API it expects a single JSON object, not an array of them. Therefore if you perform an HTTP PUT to CouchDB that is an array of JSON objects it returns an HTTP 400 response. Even if the array contains 1 item [{"key":"value"}] will not be accepted by CouchDB. Make sense?

Comment: Haha yes, well this has already been answered but, NSJSONSerialization doesn't require an array, as you've found out.  In fact, instead you could have simply done `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:docData options:kNilOptions error:nil]` since that by itself is a valid JSON object.  I hope you understand more about how it works now.  The reason the above method returns `id` is because it can be either `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` depending on the data it receives.  However, it is obviously cleaner for the example to do it weichsel's way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let `NSJSONSerialization` do the conversion from Foundation object to string. This guarantees proper escaping and makes the code more readable.
If you have a key-value pair as in your sample above, you could do:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{@"name": @"nick"};
NSData* putData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

You should be able to directly put that into the content of your `PUT` request, without wrapping it in an additional array. If the endpoint that handles the request requires you to send an array, you should create the array as an Foundation object (`NSArray`) and serialize that as JSON before sending it to the server:

```
NSArray* jsonArray = @[@{@"name": @"nick"}];
```

The title of your question is *"**Deserialize** JSON without wrapping in [ ]"* - Shouldn't that be *"**Serialize** JSON without wrapping in [ ]"*?
I changed it, please change it back if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: No.. I think that was an accurate edit. Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I started doing something, well, dumb. Which was to loop through the array and manually create the NSDictionary. This is much less work and much more readable. +1. Thanks man.